# Form validation how to exclude an input field?

Tags: forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I am following the bootstrap 4 form validation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

But i like to exclude an inputfield from validation. From the example

```
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
```

Nice! You got this one!
        
          Please choose a username.

and i thought by simply setting the required attribut to false it would do the trick, but it didn't work

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required="false">
```

As soon as i hit the submit button, the username field gets a green border.

I have also added this .js, should i add the excluded input field here??

```
 (function() {
        'use strict';
                window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                        // Loop over them and prevent submission
                        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                                    event.stopPropagation();
                            }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                        }, false);
                        });
                }, false);
        })();
```

Also validation on a select menu doesn't seem to work:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="type" id="add_type" required>
         <option selected disabled>Select</option>
         <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute works by either being present or absent, not by changing its value to `false`.

So use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

instead of this, where the `required` is present:

```
DON'T DO THIS
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="false">
```

which is equivalent to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required>
```

and also equivalent to

```
DON'T DO THIS
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="bananas">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required