# Any way to exclude form validation from specific input field?

Tags: html, forms, vue.js, validation

I want to use an `input url field` in a `rich text editor component (RTE)` which is placed inside a form element but it's triggering the form validation which shows `"please fill in this field"` in other input fields. Is there a way to exclude the `input url field` from form validation?

```
<input type="url" v-model="state.url" no-validation>
```

or something similar?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886871/form-validation-how-to-exclude-an-input-field) but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with vue.js, but to exclude an html input element from [built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation), you can disable it:

```html
<input type="url" maxlength="42" disabled>
```

Here I've used `maxlength` because it is a standard attribute that is used by built-in form validation.
Maybe Vue's `v-model` doesn't work the same way, but I think this is worth a try.

#### Supporting documentation

The above use of the `disabled` attribute works for me (with built-in form validation, and I've only tested it on Chrome).
But I have not found conclusive supporting documentation on MDN.

See:

- [disabled attribute: interactions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled#attribute_interactions)
- [Client-sode form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

I don't find these docs entirely clear.
They imply that using the `disabled` attribute is a legal way to get the `required` attribute to be ignored:

> Because a `disabled` field cannot have its value changed, `required` does not have any effect on inputs with the `disabled` attribute also specified. Additionally, since the elements become immutable, most other attributes, such as `pattern`, have no effect, until the control is enabled.

but also say that these 2 attributes are not permitted together:

> Note: The `required` attribute is not permitted on inputs with the `disabled` attribute specified.